# Broadcom bcm4352 wireless on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, wifi, drivers

I'm trying to set up CentOS 7 on a Dell Precision M3800 and can't get the wireless working - the only option under network settings is "wired". Any ideas how I can get a working driver?

```
$ lspci | grep Wireless
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
$ uname -r
3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: CentOS 7.0 or 7.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BCM4352 has been reported as working on CentOS 7.1.

Step 1: Determining WLAN chip and installing dependencies
Step 2: Downloading and extracting Broadcom driver archive
Step 3a: Compiling the Broadcom driver module (on EL6 and EL7)
Step 3b: Compiling the Broadcom driver module (specifics required for EL7)
Step 4a: Loading the driver module into kernel
Step 4b: Loading the driver module into kernel on boot time

[Broadcom chip models tested and reported as working](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/Wireless/Broadcom)

Answer (score 0):

You might also try the [El Repo walkthrough](https://elrepo.org/tiki/wl-kmod). It has you install the Broadcom driver as a sourceless binary. It worked well for my machine, which runs Centos 7.3 (Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64). Note that the Broadcom site says it supports Broadcom adapters for versions BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4313-, BCM4321-, BCM4322-, BCM43224-, and BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-based hardware, but it exclude version BCM4331 (the version I use). I found that it works fine for this version. Hope this is helpful.